# Initiate multiple replicas of each container on one VPS with multiple cores when using Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 20.04 with 8 CPU cores. I'm planning to use Docker in Swarm mode to serve the frontend (Vue), backend (Django) and database (PostgreSQL) through a `docker-compose.yml` file.

When I execute `docker swarm init`, Docker starts 3 containers (frontend, backend and database).

Will a single replica of each container utilize all 8 CPU cores? Or should I initiate more replicas to utilize all 8 CPU cores of my VPS?

Comment: More than 1 worker per node doesn't make sense. I am also not sure if that's even possible, just like that.

Comment: I guess I confused "worker" and "replica".

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you do not change any of the default settings or set any limits inside the compose files (resource constraints more on this - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/ or compose https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#resources), container has unlimited CPU limit and unlimited MEM limit. So one replica of each service will have ALL of the memory available if the application has means to use it.

You would probably still want to look into more replicas for options on rolling updates (updates of the SW with limited or close to zero downtime).

Comment: But how do you determine the optimal number of replicas?

Comment: Well .. i would say this is a difficult one .. it depends on your application and use case. For instance if you have an application which can only use (for instance) 4 processes to do the work, and you have big load on it, you would simply scale it more, due to that limitation (instead of making the app inside container just use more and more threads). 

Same goes, how many instances you can afford to loose. If you have 1 instance and anything happens to it (runtime error which would crash it, or gets redeployed) you have downtime, with two you already do not (same goes for updates).